# Using MySQL's LIMIT without having a real limit

Tags: java, mysql, limit

I'm forced to use a MySQL API in Java that requires a limit parameter which is appended at the end of the MySQL query (e.g. `LIMIT x`).

The problem is the fact that I don't need the limit. Should I just use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as parameter or will this caused unwanted side-effects?

Comment: Can you describe in more details which MySQL API you are using. Code samples will help.

Comment: Just try and use MySQL command line tool to do a select with `LIMIT (0, 2147483647)` and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

As it is shown in MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual ([link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)) :

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;

So if you are forced to use LIMIT, just use some large number. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 18446744073709551615;
```

But according your database structure, keep in mind [LIMIT Query Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html)